# ValueError in training GAN Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am facing a problem of ValueError again and again while trainning my GAN model.

This is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf


# read the CSV file containing the labels
labels_df = pd.read_csv('labels.csv')

# define a function to preprocess and resize the images
def preprocess_image(image, target_size):
    # convert the image to grayscale
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    # resize the image to the target size
    resized_image = cv2.resize(gray_image, target_size)
    
    # normalize the pixel values to be between 0 and 1
    normalized_image = resized_image / 255.0
    
    return normalized_image

# initialize lists to store the images and labels
images = []
labels = []

# define the target size of the resized images
target_size = (128, 128)

# iterate over the rows of the dataframe and read the corresponding image using OpenCV
for index, row in labels_df.iterrows():
    image_filename = row['image_filename']
    label = row['label']
    
    # read image using OpenCV
    image = cv2.imread(image_filename)
    
    # preprocess and resize the image
    preprocessed_image = preprocess_image(image, target_size)
    
    # save the preprocessed image and label in numpy arrays
    images.append(preprocessed_image)
    labels.append(label)

# convert the lists to numpy arrays
images = np.array(images)
labels = np.array(labels)

# save the numpy arrays to disk
np.save('preprocessed_images.npy', images)
np.save('labels.npy', labels)



# load the preprocessed images and labels from the numpy arrays
images = np.load('preprocessed_images.npy')
labels = np.load('labels.npy')

# define the input shape of the generator
generator_input_shape = 100

# define the generator model
generator = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(7 * 7 * 64, input_dim=generator_input_shape),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((7, 7, 64)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, kernel_size=7, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')
])

# define the discriminator model
discriminator = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, input_shape=(28, 28, 1), padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

# define the batch size and number of epochs
batch_size = 12
epochs = 10

# define the labels for the real and fake images
real_labels = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
fake_labels = np.zeros((batch_size, 1))

# define the GAN model by combining the generator and discriminator
gan = tf.keras.Sequential([generator, discriminator])

# compile the GAN model
discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5))
gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5))

# iterate over the epochs
for epoch in range(epochs):
    # select a random batch of images
    idx = np.random.randint(0, images.shape[0], batch_size)
    real_images = images[idx].reshape(batch_size, 28, 28, 1) # corrected
    
    # generate a batch of fake images
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, generator_input_shape))
    fake_images = generator.predict(noise)

    # train the discriminator on real and fake images
    real_labels = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
    fake_labels = np.zeros((batch_size, 1))
    d_loss_real = discriminator.train_on_batch(real_images, real_labels)
    d_loss_fake = discriminator.train_on_batch(fake_images, fake_labels)

    # calculate the discriminator loss for this batch
    d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)

    # train the generator to fool the discriminator
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, generator_input_shape))
    fool_labels = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
    g_loss = gan.train_on_batch(noise, fool_labels)

    # print the progress
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs} | Discriminator loss: {d_loss[0]} | Generator loss: {g_loss}")


discriminator.summary()

generator.summary()
```

Error Message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 53
     50 for epoch in range(epochs):
     51     # select a random batch of images
     52     idx = np.random.randint(0, images.shape[0], batch_size)
---> 53     real_images = images[idx].reshape(batch_size, 28, 28, 1) # corrected
     55     # generate a batch of fake images
     56     noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, generator_input_shape))

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1048576 into shape (64,28,28,1)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Generator Summary:

```
Model: "sequential_9"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense_6 (Dense)             (None, 3136)              316736    
                                                                 
 reshape_3 (Reshape)         (None, 7, 7, 64)          0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose_6 (Conv2DT  (None, 14, 14, 64)       65600     
 ranspose)                                                       
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_9 (Batc  (None, 14, 14, 64)       256       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_12 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 14, 14, 64)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose_7 (Conv2DT  (None, 28, 28, 64)       65600     
 ranspose)                                                       
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_10 (Bat  (None, 28, 28, 64)       256       
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_13 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 28, 28, 64)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_9 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 28, 1)         3137      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 451,585
Trainable params: 451,329
Non-trainable params: 256
```

Discriminator Summary:

```
Model: "sequential_10"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_10 (Conv2D)          (None, 14, 14, 64)        1088      
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_14 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 14, 14, 64)        0         
                                                                 
 dropout_6 (Dropout)         (None, 14, 14, 64)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_11 (Conv2D)          (None, 7, 7, 128)         131200    
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_11 (Bat  (None, 7, 7, 128)        512       
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_15 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 7, 7, 128)         0         
                                                                 
 dropout_7 (Dropout)         (None, 7, 7, 128)         0         
                                                                 
 flatten_3 (Flatten)         (None, 6272)              0         
                                                                 
 dense_7 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 6273      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 139,073
Trainable params: 138,817
Non-trainable params: 256
```

I am trying to change the batch_size but is not working. I have images of size 128*128 for training model.